# No dataset template in Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, dataset

I try to set up a dataset for a SQL connection following these instructions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171897.aspx

But I´m stuck at "Adding new dataset to application". I have no dataset template in the "Add new item" dialog.

Has anyone got an idea what I am doing wrong? I use Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Comment: Can you add the most important this from that URL in your post (in English)?

Comment: Hi, here is the direct link to the us page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171897.aspx    at the top of the german page you can switch to the Original language. I didn´t now this selection isn´t saved in the link.

Comment: To add a new dataset item to the project  1.On the Project menu, click Add New Item.  The Add New Item dialog box appears.  2.In the Templates box of the Add New Item dialog box, click DataSet.  3.Name the Dataset NorthwindDataset, and then click Add.  Visual Studio will add a file called NorthwindDataset.xsd to the project and open it in the Dataset Designer.